# Match and Match_phrase on multiple fields with the same query string- Elastic Search(Nest)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, querydsl

I have to search for a keyword on multiple fields for the same query string.

```
"bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match": {
                            "ABC": "Apple"
                         }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                            "XYZ": "Apple"
                         }
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I wrote the query DSL , it has been translated as multimatch query(Not sure if the above code and DSL are same)

```
.Bool(b => b
.Should(sh => sh
.MultiMatch(c => c
.Fields(f => f.Field(p => p.ABC).Field("XYZ"))
.Query(keyz)))))
```

Similarly i want to write a DSL query but i want to do match_phrase operation. Can some one help me in solving this.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

Given a document type

```
public class Document
{
    public string ABC { get; set; }
    public string XYZ { get; set; }
}
```

This would be

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings); 
var keyz = "Apple";

client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(sh => sh
                .Match(c => c
                    .Field(p => p.ABC)
                    .Query(keyz)
                ),
                    sh => sh
                .Match(c => c
                    .Field(p => p.XYZ)
                    .Query(keyz)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You can shorten this by **[taking advantage of operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/bool-queries.html#_operator_overloading)**

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(c => c
            .Field(p => p.ABC)
            .Query(keyz)
        )
        || q.Match(c => c
            .Field(p => p.XYZ)
            .Query(keyz)
        )
    )
);
```

Both produce

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "ABC": {
              "query": "Apple"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "XYZ": {
              "query": "Apple"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Russ. Thanks for the help. May I know why is ".DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p)" used and how does it help ? 
And I'm actually trying to run a match_phrase first and if the hits are 0  from the match_phrase query then  I plan to run Match query.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer()` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#camel-casing. It allows you to control how field names are inferred from your POCO property names. You could run a `match_phrase` and a `match` at the same time with a `bool` query

Comment: Thanks Russ. But I want to run match_phrase on both the fields first, and if results are 0 then want to run a match query on those fields again. I'm not planning to do a match_phrase on one field and a match on another field. And is my multimatch DSL query wrong?

Comment: I understand - I'm suggesting that you may not need to use two separate requests to achieve what you want. The syntax of your `multi_match` is correct.

Comment: Ohh okok. I understand now. So that means I can write both match_phrase and a match query in the same bool using "should" for these two queries?? Is it possible to write a match_phrase with two queries(like search for `query:Apple` and `type: ".pdf"`) and match with one query in the same query?  And one more thing Russ. When I used your code, I get 0 results even after adding the defaultFieldNameInferrer in connection settings where as multimatch is retrieving values. Did I miss something ?

Comment: `bool` queries can be nested `n` levels deep so can express any combination of queries combined with `must`, `should` and `must_not`. 

I used `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer` as you have uppercase POCO property names and send through uppercase field names in the query. If your mapping does not use uppercase field names, don't use the *example* code verbatim :)

Comment: I didnt use `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer` . As the results were 0 i just checked if i missed anything and so added it and checked. The only difference between your code and my code is at this place, **mycode**: ` "match": {"ABC": "Apple"}` and **yourcode**: ` "match": {
            "XYZ": {
              _"query": "Apple"_
            }
          }`